# c# asp.net waiting for state in db to change

Tags: asp.net, database, asynchronous

I am building a web application where a job submitted by user is handled by a background service and the communication between web app and background service is done on database. So when a search starts, web application inserts a record into db and waits till the status field of the record changes. As I understand, if I implement this on the request thread, I am blocking one of the pool threads unnecessarily, but cannot get my head around to do this asynchronously. What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Could you put a "loading" placeholder in and use javascript/ajax to query a service every 5...10..15...30 seconds (whatever makes sense for your use case/anticipated load) to see when the results are ready, then redirect the user to a results page/refresh the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server as your DB then you can use a ADO.NET feature called SQLDependency,

What this dose when setup correctly is, when ever there is a change in table (which you will configure) a C# event will be raised. 
Here is a article that expains it

Note: You will have to setup your SQL server to enable this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events

And this one expains how to refresh page after data in table has changed

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3w8402y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

SQLDependency is very useful, but on the server side it provided only half the solution. I overcame the other half by using SignalR to signal the client that the query is over. In the end it was quite an efficient and elegant solution. Thanks for the info!

```
    public class KYHub : Hub
{
    void OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDependency dependency = sender as SqlDependency;
        dependency.OnChange -= OnChange;
        if (e.Info != SqlNotificationInfo.Error && e.Info != SqlNotificationInfo.Delete)
        {
            string connstr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnnStr"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            conn.Open();
            SearchResult result= SearchResult.Parse(conn, Caller.TaskID);
            conn.Close();
            Caller.endsearch(result);
        }
    }

    public void Search(SearchParam search)
    {
        string connstr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnnStr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        conn.Open();
        search.ClientID = Caller.id;
        int QueryID = search.Save(conn);
        Caller.TaskID = QueryID;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Completed FROM dbo.Tasks WHERE TaskID={0}", QueryID), conn);
        SqlDependency dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
        dep.OnChange += OnChange;
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution.  Just trying to learn about this now and other documentation suggests that a call to `SqlDependency.Start(m_ConnectionString);` is needed.  Where did you put this or is this not needed?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I put the call to SqlDependency.start in Global.asax